# Unable to uninstall\upgrade Electron

Tags: npm, electron

I tried to update Electron, but even though it has been updated to the latest version successfully using `npm install electron@latest` , I still get the old version when running the app with `electron .`

In DevTools inside the app, the output of `navigator.userAgent.match(/Electron\/([\d\.]+\d+)/)[1]` remains `8.2.1`.

So I have installed a fresh quick-start Electron boilerplate, same error, package.json points to version 16+ and the Electron app itself uses the old `8.2.1` version.

So I tried to uninstall Electron, but... couldn't:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Code\app> npm uninstall electron

removed 41 packages, and audited 291 packages in 2s

35 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS C:\Users\User\Code\app> npm uninstall electron -g

removed 86 packages, and audited 1 package in 1s

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS C:\Users\User\Code\app> electron .

(electron) The default value of app.allowRendererProcessReuse is deprecated, it is currently "false".  It will change to be "true" in Electron 9.
```

(The last raw means that the app is running with an alert that belongs to Electron version 8)

Where is this Electron version hiding?

Comment: Try deleting the global npm folder located at `%AppData%/Roaming/npm`, note that you'll loose all your globally Installed packages, you'll have to install them back.

Comment: Just did, still `electron -v` is available globally with `v8.2.1` output

Comment: Try `where electron` on your command prompt. It will show you the path hth the executable

Comment: Furthermore it might also be, that some package you have in your current project depends on electron, so it won't be uninstalled from your package even if you do `npm uninstall` (because that would break dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, Electron had been installed in another project I had on the same machine, not globally.

To locate the installation, type:

`electron`

And it will open a default Electron app that has all the details regarding the location of the installed package.
[image: Electron Window]